# I have a file having some columns. I would like to do sort for column 2 by grouping column 1 values

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sorting

I have a file having some columns. I would like to do sort for column 2 by grouping column 1 values.

See below example.

Input File like:

```
NEW,RED,1
OLD,BLUE,2
NEW,BLUE,3
OLD,GREEN,4
```

Expected output file:

```
NEW,BLUE,3
NEW,RED,1
OLD,BLUE,2
OLD,GREEN,4
```

How can i achieve this,please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sort -t, -k1,2 inputfile
NEW,BLUE,3
NEW,RED,1
OLD,BLUE,2
OLD,GREEN,4
```

`-t` is used to specify the field separator, and `-k1` to specify the starting/ending key positions.